# CanActivate vs redirect in constructor

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I've seen a lot of questions about using DI for the `@CanActivate` decorator. I'm aware of the implementation of a custom Injector to provide the `Router`.

My question is more about the general design: What are the advantages (or disadvantages) of using `@CanActivate` over just redirecting inside the equivalent component constructor. Is the last one a bad solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CanActivate` is especially designed to be completely outside the component. This is why it's difficult to inject the `Router`. With the constructor a component instance would need to be created and then immediately destroyed because of the redirect.

Comment: So you would recommend using `CanActivate` and injecting both a service and the router?

Comment: It might depend on the use case. But in general yes. And there are plans to improve the limitation with DI in `CanActivate`.